# What is H264Layer profile and level?

Tags: android, ios, youtube, video-encoding, azure-media-services

I am not familiar with video encoding, so this could be a silly question:

What does the H264 layer "profile" and "level" means?

To be exact, I am trying to use Azure Media service to encode some videos, and I noticed these settings in its configure. In its own page, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269962.aspx, it doesn't really explain anything. For example, for "profile", it simply says "Auto, Baseline, Main, High".

My goal is to encode the video in a way that can be played back on most platforms (Windows, iOS, Android), so I want to see if I can find some settings that work for all of them - from Azure's own document, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt269960.aspx, it hints that for different platforms, I'd better encode / generate different output files. Is that the case? (does YouTube have different video files for different platforms, for the same input content file?)

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://blog.mediacoderhq.com/h264-profiles-and-levels/), [This](http://www.paradiso-design.net/H264_AVC.html) & [this](http://www.img.lx.it.pt/~fp/artigos/H264_final.pdf) will be helpful

Comment: Thanks! It is very helpful! -- And about the last question: anyone has some good recommended values that work for most devices/browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out: looks like profile baseline or main, level 3.1, is a good bet that fits most devices. Of course, I may need different bitrates.